simple-salesforce create a task or create a call log. python api
using python api  simple-salesforce, https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/
i want to create a task or call log.
is it possible?
I saw a failed attempt here
I tried
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(instance_url=sf_db.instance_url, session_id=sf_db.access_token)
# "sf" works on getting and creating contacts.

call_log_data = {
            "WhoId": contact_id,  # ID of the contact
            "Subject": "My subject",  # Subject of the call log
            "ActivityDateTime": "2024-04-08",  # Date and time of the call
            "Description": "anything",  # Notes about the call
        }

    result = sf.Task.create("Task", call_log_data)


got an error on task.create
[{\'message\': "Json Deserialization failed on token \'null\' and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row", \'errorCode\': \'INVALID_FIELD\'}]'}

below are just ui images of the salesforce console in which i want to do the equivalent of in an API.



"Description": "anything", - is that comma at the end breaking stuff?

no. its not breaking it.

turns out it was this. had to remove the 1st arg.
result = sf.Task.create(call_log_data)
this creates a task. but i want to create a call log. any ideas?

From what I remember "logging calls" just makes Tasks with Status = Completed, Type = Call, Origin = Phone... You'd have to examine existing ones and compare?

a JSON deserialization issue, which might be related to how the data is being formatted before sending it to Salesforce.
# Create the Task
result = sf.Task.center code herereate(call_log_data)

# Check the result
if result['success']:
    print("Task created successfully. Task ID:", result['id'])
else:
    print("Failed to create Task. Error:", result['errors'])

try this task.
